# Configure azure credentials inside DotNetCoreCLI@2 task

Tags: .net, azure, azure-devops

I need to make an api call to an azure resource within a test file. I run those tests in the pipeline with the DotNetCoreCLI@2 task. The test relies on the [DefaultAzureCredential](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.identity.defaultazurecredential?view=azure-dotnet) (which itself enumerates several credential providers) but I am struggling to understand how I can tell the build agent to set one of these credentials. I tried creating my own credential provider implementation by setting an environment variable using the pipeline provided token, but that doesn't work.

```cs
    public override AccessToken GetToken(TokenRequestContext requestContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
      string environmentVariable = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN");
      return new AccessToken("Bearer " + environmentVariable, DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(60.0));
    }
```

```yaml
  - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
    displayName: 'dotnet test'
    env:
      SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN: $(System.AccessToken)
    inputs:
      SecretsFilter: "*"
      command: test
      arguments: --collect "Code coverage"
      projects: ${{ parameters.testProjects }}
```